# How to creat UITable, UIButton, UILable, UIImage, UIText, UISlider, UINavigationBar, UITabBar programiticly?

Tags: iphone

I'm new with the iphone programming and I'm trying to know how to create all of these (UI's) without using the IB, so I'm only asking for the code lines that will create each one of these.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to figure this out is to read through the documentation for each of these classes. Some which are subclasses of `UIView` can be instantiated with [`-initWithFrame:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/initWithFrame:), for example.

Answer (score 1):

i am new to iphone/ipad programming , i fallowed below links  to create views programmatically... i think these are helpful to  u also >>

### To create UIButton,UILabel,UIImage,UITextField programmatically

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/implement-uibutton-uitextfield-and-uilabel-programmatically-in-iphone/

### To create UITableView Programatically

http://thesdkblog.com/2011/05/how-to-setup-a-uitableview-programmatically/

### To create UINavigationController and UITabbarController Programmatically

http://codenugget.org/how-to-embed-a-navigation-controller-inside-a

http://www.xdracco.net/howto-implement-uinavigationcontroller-uitabbarcontroller-programmatically/

Thanks u..

Answer (score 0):

I've Noticed that a lot of people viewed this question, so I was doing a search on this subject and I came through a great sample code, which can explain how to do a lot of things and here is the link to that sample code:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/uicatalog/Introduction/Intro.html

I hope that this will help.